# Trying to obtain updated locations of android phone but code giving me problems

Tags: android, location

I am trying to update the location of the phone periodically, but I am getting some errors with my code. Here it is:

```
LocationManager locm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
Location location = locm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

double longitude = location.getLongitude();
double latitude = location.getLatitude();



private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    locm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS, 2000, 10, locationListener);
        // error here : Syntax error on token(s), misplaced constructs
```

The thing is, when I take out the last line of code, there are no errors in the code. Can somebody help me please?? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss the closing bracket in the new location listener.

```
private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }
}; <--
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I am getting two errors on the same line, saying : "Syntax error on token "(", < expected" and "Syntax error on token, ConstructorHeaderName expected instead". What does that mean?

Comment: This means you are trying to execute a method outside any method / initialization block. it is related to this line: "locm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS, 2000, 10, locationListener);" and if you want to perform it outside any method you will need to use initialization block. see some examples here: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0100__Class-Definition/0140__Initialization-Block.htm

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this nice library project I found. It's nicely documented and is Apache License 2.0.

http://code.google.com/p/little-fluffy-location-library/

Answer (score 0):

Your last line ("locm.resquestLocationUpdates...") needs to be within a method.  It looks like it's directly in a class.